# jquery clone doesn't work in IE

Tags: jquery, html, clone, input-type-file

Below piece of code works in Chrome and Firefox, but NOT with Internet Explorer. When I run the html ... select a file ... and then click on the button ... a second "input type=file" should appear with the same file selected. This happens in Chrome and Firefox, but NOT in IE ... in IE the second "input type=file" is empty.

Does anyone know how to get it working in IE ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script
        src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">

    </script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#btn').click(function(){
                var newElement = $('#file1').clone();
                newElement.appendTo($("#div1"));
            })
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="div1">
        <input type="file" id="file1">
    </div>  

    <button id="btn">button</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what version of IE are you using? And have you checked that it isn't running in IE8 compatibility mode?

Comment: I'm using IE 11. It's not running in IE8 compatibility mode.